# What permissions are required on Azure DevOps to Publish NPM Packages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I'd like to ensure I have properly setup permissions on Azure DevOps.

What are the required permissions for this?

Comment: manually from your laptop? because build agent has got those by default, you dont need to configure everything

Comment: The actual act of publishing new Artifacts, from local machine, to NPM.  Maybe it's NPM permissions actually?  Not even Azure DevOps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780741/user-lacks-permission-to-complete-this-action-you-need-to-have-addpackage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [feed permissions docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops), you need ***contributor permissions*** to *push* to the feed:

| Permission | Reader | Collaborator | Contributor | Owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| List, install, and restore packages | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |
| Push packages |  |  | ✓ | ✓ |
| Unlist/deprecate packages |  |  | ✓ | ✓ |
| Delete/unpublish package |  |  |  | ✓ |
| Promote a package to a view |  |  | ✓ | ✓ |
| Add/remove upstream sources |  |  |  | ✓ |
| Save packages from upstream sources |  | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |
| Edit feed permissions |  |  |  | ✓ |
| Allow external package versions |  |  |  | ✓ |

In order to [check or add feed permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#adding-usersgroups-permissions-to-a-feed), go to Artifacts > Gear Icon > Permissions

[image: Feed Permissions Settings]