# Azure DevOps: User lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I get an error:

```
User XXX lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'
```

when trying to push a nuget package to Azure DevOps artifacts. I am the administrator
This is the stage:

```
  - stage:
    displayName: 'Release'
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - job: 'Publish'
        displayName: 'Publish nuGet Package'
        steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: $(PIPELINE_ARTIFACT_NAME)
            displayName: 'Download pipeline artifact'
          - script: ls $(PATH_PIPELINE_ARTIFACT_NAME)
            displayName: 'Display contents of downloaded articacts path'
          - task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
            displayName: 'Authenticate in NuGet feed'
          - script: dotnet nuget push $(PATH_PIPELINE_ARTIFACT_NAME)/**/*.nupkg --source $(NUGET_FEED) --api-key $(NUGET_API_KEY)
            displayName: 'Uploads nuGet packages'
```

And the exact error:

```
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User '4a2eb786-540d-4690-a12b-013aec2c86e5' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'. (DevOps Activity ID: XXXXXXX-6DF9-4A98-8A4E-42C556C6FC56)).
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Uploads nuGet packages
```

The git repo is in GitHub. Not sure who is considered to be the user but I don't know which other permissions to modify

Answer (score 169, accepted):

It seems I fixed by adding to the feed's permission settings the Build Service as Contributor.

It's a bit confusing tbh but it's now working fine.

[image]

Comment: BTW, it is in `...` menu next to Delete, called `Add project-scoped builds`

Comment: I had Build Service as Contributor and I start getting the error at some point (it was working fine before that). What it fixed it, for me, was removing Build Service from the permissions list and re-adding it.

Comment: Similar to Kord i had "Project Collection Build Service (XXXXXX-XXXXXX)" as a user, I had to remove it, then use the "...." icon and click "Add Builds and releases" which , by clicking, re-added the user... with appropriate permissions. I can now successfully use mvn deploy in my pipeline and deploy to the azure artifact area

Comment: One note to add, my feed was in another project, so I thought I had to switch to that project and then click "Add project-scoped builds". Actually I needed to go to Artifacts inside the project that was building and then follow the instructions.

Comment: Just incase anyone runs into it, searching for the user after clicking "Add users/groups" does not work with partial names. ie, searching for "build" or "Build Service" will not pull up the appropriate account, but if you search for "<project> Build Service (<org>)" it'll come up as expected. 
This was fairly annoying to figure out.

Comment: I don't know what makes the difference but this solution was not working for me until I changed the agent specificaction for the job from windows-latest to windows-2019.

Comment: @PeterBernier Argh! That's what I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: @diegosasw wow. thnx. This was what I was missing.

Comment: I got this after i enabled the Project Settings `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` even though the user was Project Collection Build Service.

Comment: The error in the pipeline execution pointed to a user guid, which was not the same as the Build service guid listed in the permissions.  Nonetheless, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @PeterBernier! In my instance, I had to add a second user/groups with the contributor role, the one specified by @PeterBernier and; Project Collection Build Service (<org>)

Comment: What helped for me is removing `Project Collection Build Service ([Org])` and/or removing and re-adding `[ProjectName] Build Service ([Org])`

Answer (score 86):

Steps:

1. Click on **Artifacts** on the left side.
2. Select your feed from the drop down (usually selected by default)
3. Click the **Feed Setting** gear on the top right corner.
4. Click **Permissions**
5. Click **Add Users/groups** and search for **{your org} Build Service** and add as **Contributor**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This was detailed. Modified the answer by highlighting the key items to click on.

Comment: Clear cut answer with text highlighting , helped me save time

Answer (score 47):

For those who are completely lost like me, the page mentioned by @diegosasw is in the Artifacts menu, not in the Task or in the Pipeline:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for actually pointing this out again. I was also lost, your screenshot helped me!

Answer (score 24):

A few things have changed in at least the Azure Devops web interface as of 2022-07. Although the fundamentals appear unchanged, the `...` button talked about earlier is gone. Below are the steps I figured at the time of writing. Extracted from a [bit of a whinging blog post](https://jmp75.github.io/work-blog/azure/devops/microsoft/2022/07/27/azure-devops-negative-experience.html), which has more details and context.

[image: artifacts tab in AZ menu]

Create a new feed, setting the scope to the project:

[image: feed creation settings]

By default, the permission list created for the new feed is as below. Note that the `organisation_name Build Service (project_name)` user or group has the role `Collaborator` by default. This may be the key stumbling block users trip over.

[image: default feed permissions]

You cannot change the role; you have to remove the `organisation_name Build Service (project_name)` user or group and add it again with the `Contributor` role.

[image: corrected feed permissions]

Comment: You save me. I need to delete and add it again, and solved. Thank you

Comment: To change roles, you don't need to remove them, just re-add them and the role will change.

Answer (score 14):

My solution was slightly different. New pipelines default to "Current Project" under Pipeline > Edit > Options > Build job > Buld job authorization scope.... this needed changing to "Project collection", which solved the problem:

[image]

Comment: This solved it for me :)

Answer (score 11):

Great find! Allowing project-scoped builds in the ... menu worked for me.

But in order to be able to push the package from Azure Pipelines to the Azure Artifacts feed at all, I had to add the same feed as Target feed under the dotnet restore step before dotnet build and finally dotnet push. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/dotnet-exe?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 9):

See `ArkadiuszKozie-6872`'s answer here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/723164/granting-read-privileges-to-azure-artifact-feed.html

Had to grant `Contributor` to `Project Collection Build Service (<YOUR-ORG-NAME>)` too, which fixed it for me.

Comment: This was it for me as well, it may be tied to multi-repo project, but this user was the last piece of the puzzle. Comment left for future readers...

Answer (score 8):

the correct answer is, at the artifact settings page (you can access following the explanation above)  you need to add contributor permission to the user with the name pattern [project_name] Build Service. For example, if your project name is "IoT" you need to find the user "IoT Build Service" at the  Add user/groups in the permission tab as shown above and assign the contributor permission.

Answer (score 7):

Just a note - make sure you put your Build Service as **Contributor**.
I had mine as **Collaborator** which is a completely different role and I didn't notice the difference since they just appear very similar.

Answer (score 3):

If you still got the error, you could try to add the Team as Contributor as well.

Hope it works.

[project_name][project_name] Team - Contributor

project_name Build Service(Org_name) - Contributor

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact problem. Under *Feed Settings -> Permissions* I could locate the `Project Collection Build Service (Organization)` with the Contributor permissions but did not work. As a solution I removed that and added `"Project Name" Build Service (Organization)`. This is the build service for the project on which I have created the pipeline specifically.

Answer (score 2):

On the feed view, it's over here (as of 11/2023):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just an extra information when using `"Project Name" Build Service (Organization)`, even of the search does not return any result, the save button becomes enabled if the name is correct