# Is "Allow project-scoped builds" required in addition to Project Collection Build Service

Tags: azure-pipelines

My build failed as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780741/user-lacks-permission-to-complete-this-action-you-need-to-have-addpackage) however unlike aforementioned, Project Collection Build Service was already marked as Contributor.  I solved the issue by checking "Allow project-scoped builds".  This added another user named [Project name] Build Service.

Shouldn't the Project Collection Build Service permission allow me to create the build? I don't understand why I have to set Allow project-scoped builds for each project.  I'm going to forget this and I will need to look it up again when the build fails on my next project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the **Project Collection Build Service** is a Contributor. If you've changed your builds to run at [project scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope), you'll need to add the project-level build identity as a Reader or Contributor.

You could check the Pipeline settings under your Azure DevOps **Organization settings**:

- If **Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release
  pipelines** is enabled, then the scope is **project**.
- If **Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release
  pipelines** is not enabled, then check the Pipeline settings under your
  **Project settings** in Azure DevOps:

  - If **Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release
    pipelines** is enabled, then the scope is **project**.
  - Otherwise, the scope is **collection**.